# Is there a more general word for velocitized?

Tags: single-word-requests, common-word

Velocitized, meaning being accustomed to high driving speeds and feeling like normal speeds are slower than they actually are afterwards, seems like such a useful word to apply in different situations.

> I went mountain biking and going to work the next day was **_____**.

I've used *culture shock* to describe this in the past, but that's obviously not always an appropriate connotation. Is there a more general word for this?

Comment: *mundane* fits the blank in your sentence but is nowhere close to your "velocitized" word. *Desenitized* might be closer.

Comment: "Dude, it feels like I'm living in *slow-mo*".

Comment: ...like a Sunday drive.

Comment: If it is a change from difficult to easier ...`child's play` is one option

Comment: I should clarify, I think that my example wasn't far enough away from the speed thing. I want this for other situations like going from a first-person shooter to a puzzle game or the emotional high from a weekend vacation to normal day to day life.

Comment: Ah, you're describing the high cost of *context-switching*. You can say you're "*lagged*".

Comment: Why not just "slow"? (which means dull, boring, uninteresting also)

Comment: Are you able to reword your sentence to use "acclimatised?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention "shock", you might consider using the word *jarring*:

> ***jarring***: incongruous in a striking or shocking way; clashing
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries (US)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/jarring)</sub>

If you are wanting to impart the notion that you changed from doing something largely different from something else, you might want to consider *contrasting* or more obscurely *contrastive*.

If you are wanting to describe the feeling of doing something much less exciting than what you were doing before, you can consider *humdrum*.

Comment: I had thought up a metaphorical phrase to use: ... going to work the next day gave me ***mental whiplash***. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> *Time, with all its **celerity**, moves slowly to him whose
>    whole employment is to watch its flight.* --Johnson.

"[*Celerity*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/celerity)" means "speed" or "swiftness", but it's got that high-Latin feel so common in medical conditions and pathologies.  As an adjective, it would be rendered "*celeritous*" (credit to @Anonym for that one).

If you want to underscore the "suffering under a condition" aspect of it, and you're ok with novel coinings, you might want to apply that good old suffix, "-itis" (yes, in a literal sense, it does mean "inflammation", but in a more abstract, metaphorical context, it's used to mean "sickness"):

> ***celeritis***: inflicted with unnaturally increased speed

Comment: Since the querent seems to be asking for an adjective, *celeritous* may be more fitting.

Comment: @Anonym Good point, I'll include that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[disorienting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disorienting)* (or *disorientating*)

> to cause (someone) to lose his bearings [*Collins*]